# Snowboy and Python - when testing demo.py bash chooses wrong file directory?

Tags: python

I'm trying to use the simple python demo.py snowboy.udml on bash and it constantly says it cant find my file - that's because the directory its suggesting doesn't exist - how can i change this on bash so it leads to the correct working directory with my demos inside it??

Answer (score 0):

To move to your script directory just use the `cd` command:

```
cd directoryname
```

Otherwise, you can specify the path to the files like this:

```
python /path/demo.py /path/snowboy.udml
```

I can't say more because I'm not sure of what you're asking, I hope this helps you.